# Cannot swap on /dev/xvda9 (always busy?)

Tags: swap

I have plenty of of those errors in my syslog

```
dev-xvda9.swap: Job dev-xvda9.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

When I try that manually, it says why:

> michael.heuberger@binarykitchen /v/log ❯❯❯ sudo swapon /dev/xvda9
>   --verbose swapon: /dev/xvda9: found signature [pagesize=4096, signature=swap] swapon: /dev/xvda9: pagesize=4096, swapsize=134217728,
>   devsize=134217728 swapon /dev/xvda9 swapon: /dev/xvda9: swapon failed:
>   Device or resource busy

For reference

```
michael.heuberger@binarykitchen /v/log ❯❯❯ cat /etc/fstab                                                                                                                                        ⏎
/dev/xvda1      /       ext3    grpquota,usrquota,rw    0       1
#UUID=3b47a57b-7e3a-47ac-81b9-a08af46d1a31
/dev/xvda9 swap      swap    defaults        0 0
```

Any ideas/suggestions where to start? Using Ubuntu 17.04 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swap does not have a mount point.
edit /etc/fstab to read:

#UUID=3b47a57b-7e3a-47ac-81b9-a08af46d1a31
/dev/xvda9 none      swap    sw        0 0

then reboot

Note: if the uuid is correct, it is better to use it instead of drive letter, because the drive assignment might change.

Comment: yeah, that seems to work. but now i see it is not used and has a priority of minus one? See output:

$ swapon
NAME       TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/xvda9 partition 128M   0B   -1

Comment: used is the current amount is use,when first boot up it should be zero. it looks to be working perfectly. though 128M is a bit small. general rule is twice your RAM if you hibernate.

Comment: Interesting... the mount point field used to be ignored so it was common to specify it as "swap" but you could use anything you wanted.  It seems this has changed with the switch to systemd, which apparently lacks the intelligence to ignore the field that upstart had.

Comment: thanks guys ... and why the priority of minus one when swap should be prioritised for better performance?

Comment: I think that is so RAM gets used first

Comment: @MichaelHeuberger, swap priority only comes into play when you have multiple swaps.  Then the relative priority affects which one gets used first.